# This requires the enhanced-enums language feature to be enabled

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

everyone. I have this error when I try to load Enum. I'm using SDK 2.7.0 & Flutter 3.0.4. I don't want to update my SDK, but I need another solution. Could you please help me with this error.

```
enum MessageEnum {
  text('text'),
  image('image'),

  const MessageEnum(this.type);
  final String type;
}

// Using an extension
// Enhanced enums

extension ConvertMessage on String {
  MessageEnum toEnum() {
    switch (this) {
      case 'image':
        return MessageEnum.image;
      case 'text':
        return MessageEnum.text;
      default:
        return MessageEnum.text;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced enums is a feature introduced in Dart version 2.17.0. Though in your example I actually don't quite understand why you even need enhanced enums. What exactly is the reason for the `type` field? Since it's exactly the same as the name. Can't you just do this?:

```
enum MessageEnum { text, image }

extension ConvertMessage on String {
  MessageEnum toEnum() {
    switch (this) {
      case 'image':
        return MessageEnum.image;
      case 'text':
        return MessageEnum.text;
      default:
        return MessageEnum.text;
    }
  }
}
```